# What is the correct name for this lab technique in crystallization?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, terminology, ionic-compounds, recrystallization, teaching-lab

Take a glass rod and rub vigorously the wall of the flask, the substance will crystallize out of the solution.

Take a fire polished stirring rod and etch (scratch) the glass of your beaker. The small pieces of glass that are etched off of the beaker serve as nuclei for crystal formation

But reaching back to my halcyon years of organic synthesis and crystallization, recalling vivid memories of scratching the sides of Erlenmeyer flasks with a glass rod to induce crystallization

It's a common lab technique. But does it have a name?

Comment: I don't remember it having a name, but the idea is that the bits of glass from the scratching will serve as "seeds" (nuclei) from which crystals can form, i.e., *heterogeneous nucleation*.

Comment: Could you be a bit more verbose in your question? It makes it easier to understand.. Provide as many details as you know (do a bit of research yourself to get more details, that makes it a really good question).

Comment: OK, I have extensively googled it but I can only find descriptions, not the name. I'll add more descriptions

Comment: I've always just heard this technique described. The purpose is to provide nucleation sites which then seed the formation of crystals.

Comment: @Joseph - regarding the notion that scratching abrades glass particles off the beaker which act as nucleation sites, I'm not convinced. My suggestion would be that the points of contact between the stirring rod and the beaker _are_ nucleation sites.

Comment: @Richard: I suppose it depends on what the rod and the container are made of. Borosilicate glass has Mohs hardness ~ 6, and flint glass in stirring rods has Mohs hardness ~ 7, so it is likely that you can scratch off bits of Pyrex from a container if your rod is hard enough. (Rods might also be made from borosilicate, in which case both the rod and the container might contribute glass bits.)

Comment: @J.M. - Regarding the Moh's hardness difference - interesting. Shouldn't borosilicate glassware acquire a 'memory' of where it has been scratched (due to the ablation of material from that point) which would obviate future scratching, however?

Comment: @Richard Terret, You are absolutely right, and btw. the need of a fire polished glass rod is nonsense. A old and scratched one is sufficient. I see the nucleation from the (ultra)sound or cavitation happening at the rubbed surfaces. Think of the "starters" used in those hand warmer bags with sodium acetate. A name for the lab technik is "rub". :=)

Comment: @Richard: I've seen flasks acquiring streaks on the bottom from their continued use in recrystallizations over the years by students in lab classes. It doesn't seem like the scratches are initially apparent (unless one rubs really hard), but the effects of the scratching will show up over time.

Comment: @Georg (and Richard)- I agree. I'm not so sure that it is the "microscopic flecks of glass" so much as the sonic disruption of a supersaturated solution. I have accomplished something similar by flicking the flask hard with my fingernail. BTW, I've always called (and heard called) this technique "scratching".

Comment: @Ben right, "scratching"! My English was so-so in grammar school, and did not improve much later :=( What do You think about "itch"? :=)

Answer (score 7):

I think the most specific you can get on this phenomenon is *nucleation* , specifically [heterogenous nucleation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleation#Heterogeneous_nucleation) / surface nucleation.

The rough surface formed creates scope for nucleation to occur, and  this creates the crystals.

I don't think there is a specific name for this technique as a lab tenchique .

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, my senior lecture has called this method 'scratching' and said that this is a widely used term.
The term nucleation is used to aid the description of the technique 'seeding' where a couple of grains of the pure substance you are creating is added to act as a nuclei for crystallisation to take place upon.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the term you are looking for is trituration.  The word itself has other meanings, but this method of inducing crystallisation is one.

Comment: No trituration exploits relative solubilities for purification. It isn't about forming the initial crystals from solution.

Comment: If you're correct, why would one be attempting to exploit these solubilities in the first place? The terminology applies to both adding solvent to dissolve impurities vs product (or vice versa ) as well as using a solvent mix or volatile solvent to dissolve and subsequently attempt crystallisation