# Scratching the inside of a flask to crystallize aspirin - what is it called and has it been scaled up?

Tags: synthesis, recrystallization

I've just watched the [Periodic Table of Videos on Aspirin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amTAuK25P6c) and saw some "tricks" used to induce crystallization after the synthesis. Rapid heating with a heat gun followed by rapid cooling in ice was not sufficient, but scratching the bottom of the flask with a stirrer seems to have triggered rapid crystallization.

**Warning:** For those who are sensitive to the sound of chalk or fingernails on blackboards, better lower the volume during the actual scratching starting after `07:10`, it's quite loud!

There is a little bit of an explanation for how the scratching helps:

> When you scratch it you are actually forming a nice surface for the crystals to aggregate on.

but I am not sure I really understand what is really happening.

**Question:** Is the scratching just glass-on-glass? Is this crystallization happening on the (probably) invisibly small scratches only, or does it happen throughout the solution? Is there an "official" name for this technique? Has it ever been scaled up in some way?

For example, [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/8786/16035) says that the scratching produces a rough surface on the bottom of the glass for nucleation, but [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/44486/16035) says it is shards of glass in solution that are providing the nucleation sites. I'm trying to understand what is actually happening when chemists rub stirrers on the inside of flasks to induce crystallization, and once that's understood, to find out if the phenomenon is scaled up in manufacturing situations.

---

[image]

**below:** "Before" and "after" screenshots showing the clear liquid becomes thick with crystals after scratching the glass.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @andselisk there is no accepted answer there, and all three answers there would not even approach a complete answer to this question; *glass-on-glass?  on the scratches only, or  throughout the solution? Has it ever been scaled up?* so no, it is not possibly a duplicate. Not even close. Also, other answers here claim it is particles of glass in solution, not the scratches themselves, so I'm really looking for a more comprehensive understanding of what is happening.

Comment: Your question is not an exact duplicate, but it's very close to that question. If you seek an accepted answer, have a look at this one: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/44486/41328

Comment: @andselisk The nucleation on shards explanation directly contradicts the nucleation on scratches explanation in your first link. Which is it? Where is the nucleation happening, on the scratches or in the solution? I'm looking for a definitive answers, not just a list of possibilities. Let's get something authoritative and conclusive, and then we can mark those questions as duplicate and point to the superior answer here. The goal in SE is good answers. In the mean time, I'll add links to both contradictory answers in my question. Thanks!

Comment: I see no contradiction as nucleation can occur both on the scratched glass surface and/or any particles present in the solution (shards, dust, density fluctuation etc.).

Comment: @andselisk why not leave the question open and see what other people think. It's quite possible someone more knowledgable will come along and know *what is happening* definitively, not just be able to make a list of what might be happening. SE is not best served by insta-closing questions that could produce more meaningful answers. Those answer could be considered pure opinion, as neither offers any way to confirm their hypothesis. No supporting links. Let's be scientific and see if we can find out if it is really known what is going on, or if those are just guesses.

Comment: I expressed my opinion, and you expressed yours. Now you claim I lack knowledge and that I should retract my close vote at the same time reminding in every comment how SE works. Wow. Bravo!

Comment: @andselisk I'm looking for someone who knows what's happening here, and who will answer my question definitively. Let's focus on getting an authoritative, non-contradictory answer. The insta-close prevents this from happening.

Comment: @uhoh I believe you are correct that this does not constitute a duplicate because the other similar questions do not have well founded answers. I would just recommend trying to not get frustrated. Don't let a misunderstanding devolve into a heated argument.

Comment: @Tyberius I don't see any of that. Insta-closes can snowball, so I've tried to encourage the user to reverse the close vote by explaining that I'm looking for someone who may have some knowledge of what's really happening, and that a quick-close would prevent that person from leaving an answer. It looks like andselisk has tried to make that look like it was something very different from what it is. If you read [the comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82795/#comment146806_82795) again you'll see it's quite innocuous. *Everyone has different knowledge, and SE lets us share.*

Comment: I doubt anyone has scaled it up, as for large scale runs, you're likely to have seed crystals of the compound itself you can use for nucleation, and these would work much better than the random nucleation you get from scratched glass.

Comment: @R.M. If it is the introduction of "shards of glass" into the solution that makes scratching effective, then I think it's fair to call introduction of silica nanoparticles or other *non-target compound particles* as scaling-up, but as you suggest, introducing particles of the target compound itself would not qualify. Thanks for the comment.